# How to use replaceAll() to replace arithmetic(i.e 0+1)

Tags: java, replaceall

so I'm currently working on a program and for part of it I need to replace AND/OR evaluations that are strings. Things like 1+0 meaning 1 OR 0. However when I try to use replaceAll("1+0", "1") it doesn't replace it. My current code is

`String test = "ab*0+1";`

```
test = test.replaceAll("0+1", "1");

System.out.println(test);
```

The output for this however gives me just

`ab*0+1`.

I did a quick println of test.indexOf("0+1") and it gave me 3. So I know that the program can see it, it just won't replace it. Any ideas?

Comment: `replaceAll` takes a _regular expression_ as a parameter.

Comment: A helpful tool for learning regular expressions: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Thank you @Mshnik that tool helped me with the next part I needed. Never worked with regular expressions before.

Answer (score 1):

Change the second line to:

```
test = test.replaceAll("0\\+1", "1");
```

`+` is interpreted in the [regex context](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and thus should be escaped.

Comment: That worked thanks so much. I haven't done a lot of string manipulation/used a lot of the methods. Definitely helpful to know

Answer (score 0):

Since [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) expects the string to define a regular expression, and `+` is special in regular expressions, your `"0+1"` means "The digit `0` one or more times, followed by the digit `1`" and would match `"01"`, `"001"`, `"00001"`, etc.

To just specify a string meant to be used literally, use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), not `replaceAll`.